# Custom PS1 prompt in .kshrc not working

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have to work with a NFS user id between two hosts: A running Ksh 93 and B running pdksh 88.

My problem has to do with the custom prompt I created on A: it works like a charm and display colors:

```
PS1="$'\E[46;31m'`logname`@$'\E[1;33m'`hostname -s`:$'\E[0m>"
```

But I switch over to B, it all goes to hell (private info removed). The prompt fails to display colors like host A ; instead, the color codes are displayed "in clear".

```
$'\E[46;31m'NFS_user_name@$'\E[1;33m'host_name_for_B:$'\E[0m>
```

The prompt on host B is not displaying colors like host A so I want B to display a basic prompt instead. To get around the problem, I edited my `.kshrc` file to add this code at the end:

```
export NODE=`uname -n`

case $NODE in
    host_name_for_B)
        PS1="[`logname`@`uname -n`]>"
        ;;
    *)
        PS1="$'\E[46;31m'`logname`@$'\E[1;33m'`hostname -s`:$'\E[0m>"
        ;;
esac
```

The case statement does not work: PS1 does not switch to

```
PS1="[`logname`@`uname -n`]>"
```

for host B.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Nowhere in your question have you said what it is that happens. How does the behavior differ from what you expect? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Have you tried putting in simple values for PS1 like "A", "B" just to check that the host-settings are being set properly?  Build things up piece by piece and see when it breaks and you'll probably work out why....

Comment: @Dennis: My bad. I thought it was obvious.  The prompt on host B is not displaying colors like host A so I want to display a basic prompt instead.

Comment: You said that the simplified prompt remains broken on host B. How?

Comment: @Dennis: what I mean is, in spite of my case statement, PS1 does not switch to PS1="[logname@uname -n]>" on Host B.

Comment: Doesn't logging in to Host B run the `.kshrc` from there? Do you have the file present in both places? If that's not the problem, then it must be that the value of `$NODE` doesn't match what you have for the match in the case statement. You need to check that the value is what you expect. Since it's private information, I can't see what is the cause of the problem. The structure of the script as you've shown it has no obvious flaws (it's not necessary to export the variable, though). Try some techniques along the lines of what Tony suggested in the comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a friend, this code for my prompt works across both hosts A and B:

```
PS1="$(printf "\033[46;31m%s@\033[1;33m%s\033[0m>" $(logname) $(hostname -s))"
```

Thanks to all for taking the time.

Comment: Works in ksh88 Version M-11/16/88f

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one which works for both pdksh and ksh93:

```
PS1='<$LOGNAME@$HOSTNAME:/${PWD#/}>'
```